# Wordpress missing attachment link

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment, custom-post-type

I have attached a pdf to a post under a custom post type - I've created a link for users to download but all that displays is Missing Attachment. I've checked the admin panel and I've definitely attached it to a post - I can't seem to get it to link to it.

My Code is:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 10;

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'stores', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'asc', 'posts_per_page' => $paged );

    $success = new WP_Query( $args );


    $output  = '';
    $output .= sprintf( "<table class='stores'>" );
    $output .= sprintf( "<tr><th>File Name</th><th>Date added</th><th>Download</th></tr>" );

    while( $success->have_posts() ) {

            $success->the_post();

            $output .= sprintf( "<tr>" );
            $output .= sprintf( "<td>%s</td>", get_the_title() );
            $output .= sprintf( "<td>%s</td>", get_the_date() );
            $output .= sprintf( "<td><a href='%s'>link</a></td>", wp_get_attachment_link()  );
            $output .= sprintf( "<tr>" );

    }

        $output .= sprintf( "</tr></table>" );
    return  $output;
```

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link

Comment: I've tried under the codex, passing an ID variable but nothing gets outputted: I've tried - $success->ID

Comment: Any particular reason you are assigning the output to a variable and returning it, as opposed to just outputting it? Also, unless you have a specific need, I'd avoid `sprintf()` and it's relations as it is a fair bit slower then just outputting.

Comment: all the code is inside a shortcode function through a plugin.

Comment: Ok, so the `retrun` of the output is necessary, but `spritnf()` is not. I've updated my answer with a few suggestions to held speed your code up. Hopefully it will be of some use to you.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_get_attachment_link()` requires the ID of your attachment, not the post that the attachment is attached to, so that it can fetch the link. -

```
wp_get_attachment_link(1234); // Replace 1234 with your relevant ID
```

To find your relevant ID, log in to your admin area, click `Media` and the click on the attachment you wish to link to. Finally, check address bar and you'll see something like `http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=7814&action=edit` - The ID you require is whatever comes after `post=`.

---

**Other Suggestions**

Firstly, I notice in your query your are mixing up your `posts_per_page` and `paged` parameters. Essentially you are telling your query to check to see if there is a page set in the query string, else show you page 10. Try this instead -

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' =>      'stores',
    'orderby' =>        'title',
    'order' =>          'ASC',
    'paged' =>          get_query_var('paged'), // The page to show
    'posts_per_page' => 10                      // How many posts to show on the page
);
```

I also notice that you use `sprintf()` regardless of whether or not it's actually required. This will slow things down, but to go even further, for just one variable I wouldn't use it at all as it's faster not too. Note also that swapping the `"` quotes for `'` quotes will speed things up (as '"' checks for variable references to convert to the String). For you Loop I recommend this code -

```
$success = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $success->have_posts() ) :

    $output.= '<table class="stores">';
    $output.= '<tr><th>File Name</th><th>Date added</th><th>Download</th></tr>';

    while( $success->have_posts() ) : $success->the_post();

        $child_args = array(
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'post_mime_type' => 'pdf',
            'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
        );
        $attachments = get_children($child_args);

        if(attachments) :
            $attachment_ID = $attachment[0]->ID
        endif;

        $output.= '<tr>';
        $output.= '<td>'. get_the_title() .'</td>';
        $output.= '<td>'. get_the_date() .'</td>';
        $output.= '<td><a href="'. wp_get_attachment_link($attachment_ID) .'">link</a></td>';
        $output.= '<tr>';

    endwhile;

    $output.= '</tr></table>';

endif;

return $output;
```

Finally, if you don't specifically need to return your output you could just output it direct, again speeding things up slightly.

Comment: Thank you for the little fix. The code is dynamic so will need to fetch the attachment link for all inside the custom post type, not just a single post.

Comment: Any error message? There may be a typo (and in fact there was, I missed a comma in the `$args` array).

Comment: Got it thanks. all works - but relating to my initial question how can I feed the id inside wp_get_attachment_link() dynamically?

Comment: Do you have a single attachment that you want to display a link for on all pages? Or does each page have it's own attachment (thus the need for dynamically grabbing the ID)?

Comment: Each custom post type has its own accompanying pdf file that's attached to it. All results are displayed in a table and the link needs to be the pdf relating to the post.

Comment: Got it. Sorry, I interpreted your question incorrectly. I'll make some changes shortly...

Comment: Oh, and does this attachment have a common name, or will that also be different for each?

Comment: A common name of link will do as the name is already being called via get_the_title().

Comment: `get_the_title()` is the title for the Post, not the Attachment. I've added some code that assumes you only have 1xPDF Attachment per Post, see how you get on with that.

Comment: Not working - I've done a var dump of $ID and its returned as null. I checked the post and the pdf is attached to it.

Comment: Ive got some more information, when debugging I get the following error at the top Notice: Undefined offset: 0